# Simulate Restore From Backup

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, backup, restore, windows-phone-8-emulator

I just wiped my Windows Phone 8.1 and restored from backup. The app that I wrote now crashes on start up. Obviously I don't want to have to do a factory reset and restore every time I need to test/debug this issue. Is it possible to simulate a restore from backup, either with a physical device or the emulator?

Comment: Where the the crash log?

Comment: Unfortunately even if there was a crash log I wouldn't be able to get at it because the app crashes at start up. However that's irrelevant to the question, the question is how can I simulate a restore from back up.

Comment: Crash logs can be retrieved irrespective of the place the app crashes. I've done development on iOS and Android and it doesn't matter where an app would crash, I still get the logs.

Comment: "The app that I wrote now crashes on start up" does this happen with a fresh install (no previous version installed) or with upgrade (installing over the previous version)?